# safari website requires a client certificate

Tags: safari, keychain, certificate, ssl

I went to a site I regularly use and got this when logging in with Safari

[image]

I seem to have 2 certificated of the same name both issued by Apple and both are not expired (found by searching in KeyChain Access app)

I evaluated at the certificates in Keychain Access and both have a status of good and the keychain they are in verifies OK.

How do I login, what are the risks in choosing the wrong one?

Comment: It's just a case of Duplicate certificates, choose any one and go forward!

Comment: @killswitch - any reference to back up that assertion and also how did it happen?